# Passing DF from function

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

i wrote a function which build a df inside it and i want to use it afterwards outside the function or in another function, how can i do it witout facing any recognition problem?

Thankw's a lot :)

The code:

```
def DisplayDataFrame():
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    df1 = pd.read_excel(file_path)
    cols = list(df1.columns)
    tree = ttk.Treeview(root)
    tree.pack()
    tree["columns"] = cols
    for i in cols:
        tree.column(i, anchor="w")
        tree.heading(i, text=i, anchor='w')
    for index, row in df1.iterrows():
        tree.insert("", 0, text=index, values=list(row))
        
option = df1.index()
```

Comment: [did you try using your favorite search engine?](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=how+to+make+a+variable+global+in+python), also probably better to use `class`es but probably for you it will be easier to use `global`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean use df1 from your DisplayDataFrame() in other functions? If so, you can have return df1 in your function like this:

```
def DisplayDataFrame():
    '''
    your original codes to define df1
    '''
    return df1

dataframe = DisplayDataFrame()
```

Then you can reuse the dataframe in other functions.

Comment: hi thanks a lot. it's not solving my problem because as you can see below the function do more things then just building a dataframe and the other things i dont want to be re run again.